# Reset Toolbar History in Matplotlib with Qt4Agg backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, qt4, toolbar

I have a separate plot thread with matplotlib and multiprocesses. Now if I interactively zoom in to the window, autoscale_view() does not work anymore (fixed with using autoscale()). But the "home" button in the Toolbox is still not working: It seems to call autoscale_view() and does not show the updated view but the old view (at point when zoomed in). Example code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("qt4agg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import multiprocessing

def reset_view():
    plt.get

    xdata = []
    ydata = []
    temp = 0

    test_ax = plt.gca()
    test_line, = plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
    plt.show(block=False)

    for i in range(10):
        temp = temp+1
        xdata.append(temp)
        ydata.append(temp)
        test_line.set_data(xdata, ydata)

        test_ax.relim()
        test_ax.autoscale(tight= False)
        plt.show(block=False)
        plt.pause(2)

plot_thread = multiprocessing.Process(target = reset_view, args = ())

reset_view()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plot_thread.start()
```

Try zooming in during plotting and pressing the Home Button after. Is there a way to either make the home button use autoscale() instead of autoscale_view() or reset & update the toolbar history, so that it doesn't jump back to old views?

P.s.: "Home"-button = reset original view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally was able to figure it out by trial & error. There is a function to update the toolbar. This updates the toolbar's history and sets the `home()` function to the new view. Solution:

```
 figure = plt.gcf() #Get current figure
 toolbar = figure.canvas.toolbar #Get the toolbar handler
 toolbar.update() #Update the toolbar memory
 plt.show(block = False) #Show changes
```